# IllegalStateException on Cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am getting this error when trying to read from the SQLite DB

> IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

```
DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readNumber(database);

String ItemId;

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //getting the ERROR here
        ItemId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.ITEMID));
        number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.PHONE_NUMBER));
        callType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.CALL_TYPE));
        callDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.CALL_DATE));
        callDuration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.CALL_DURATION));

        arrayList.add(new PhNumber(ItemId, number, callType, callDate, callDuration));
        if (debug) {
            Log.i(TAG, "DATA FOUND IN DB:\n" + "\t ID: " + ItemId + ", Number: " + number + "\n");
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    dbHelper.close();
    result = true;
    if (debug) {
        Log.d(TAG, " Number of items in DB: " + arrayList.size());
    }
}
```

readNumber

```
public Cursor readNumber(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String[] projections = {"id", DbContract.PHONE_NUMBER};
    return (database.query(DbContract.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null));
}
```

This is my DB

```
private static final String CREATE = "create table " + DbContract.TABLE_NAME +
        "(id integer primary key autoincrement,"
        + DbContract.ITEMID + " text, "
        + DbContract.PHONE_NUMBER + " text, "
        + DbContract.CALL_TYPE + " text, "
        + DbContract.CALL_DATE + " text, "
        + DbContract.CALL_DURATION + " text, "
        + DbContract.SYNC_STATUS + " text)";
```

Comment: @Zoe New here, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your projection, created by `readNumber` call, you have only the `id` and `PHONE_NUMBER` columns returned. Probably `DbContract.ITEMID` is not equal to `id` and when trying to lookup the `DbContract.ITEMID` in the cursor it is not found. To fix this you need to use `ITEMID` in `readNumber` method, something like:

```
public Cursor readNumber(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String[] projections = {DbContract.ITEMID, DbContract.PHONE_NUMBER};
    return (database.query(DbContract.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null));
}
```

Another issue is that you are trying to access other fields too, like: `CALL_TYPE`, `CALL_DATE`, etc.

So, in order to fix the issue you either:

- Do not try to retrieve the fields that are not part of the result.
- Add the needed fields in the projection too.

Answer (score 0):

**Found the issue:**
I was trying to access the columns that were not added in the projects in readNumber method adding those projections solved the issue.

> readNumber

```
    public Cursor readNumber(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String[] projections = {
            DbContract.ITEMID,
            DbContract.PHONE_NUMBER,
            DbContract.CALL_TYPE,
            DbContract.CALL_DATE,
            DbContract.CALL_DURATION};
    return (database.query(DbContract.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null));
}
```